# Forks of Metamask

Tags: metamask

Are there forks of metamask to be used to end-users in a permissioned network?
In other words, I would like to:
- hide public networks (to avoid confusion)
- pre-configure that the user should use the node of my organization (instead of Infura as default). Of course, the user can also point to other node in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there forks of metamask to be used to end-users in a permissioned network?

It's been forked over 1,000 times, so almost certainly.

> hide public networks (to avoid confusion)

See the instructions in the official documentation. ("[Adding custom networks](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/develop/docs/adding-new-networks.md)".) This details the files that will need changing.

> re-configure that the user should use the node of my organization (instead of Infura as default

There aren't any official instructions for this, but from the code it looks like this might just work from implementing the previous step.

If you remove all the existing networks which automatically use Infura in the background, then when you add your own network you can specify its new RPC endpoint URL (which isn't based on Infura).